# Object/Array loses data after sent threw Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript loop that collects data from a HTML table.

**JS**

```
//LOOP THREW TABLE ROWS
$("tr.element_row").each(function(index, element){

     var $this = $(this);
     var $inputs = $this.find("input.formData");

     formData[index] = {};

     //LOOP THREW INPUTS
     $.each($inputs, function(n, e){
         //this is each input in this tr

         if( $(this).attr('name') == 'el' ){
             formData[index]['obj'] = obj;
             formData[index]['el'] = $(this).val();
         }
         else if( $(this).attr('name') == 'lit' ){ ...
```

From this i get an object as i want it. ( console.log(formData) )
`0: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_1", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …}`
`1: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_2", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …}`
`2: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_3", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …`
`3: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_4", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …}`
`...`
`199: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_180", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …}`

Later i send this "formData" with Ajax to PHP.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'php/add_elementdata.php',
     method: 'post',
     type: 'json',
     data: {formData: formData},
     success: function(result){...
```

Now my problem accour.. Data is missing in the PHP Array.
`print_r($_POST);`will give me an array of 111 index.
`[111] => Array` <- The last array

But i actually send 199 objects.
`199: {obj: "21536", el: "BP001_180", lit: "BP001", height: "2340", type: "BP", …}`

So, is there a limit in ajax, and what it can send?
Is it possible to change this somewhere?

Comment: No, there is no limit to what you can send via AJAX. There might be limits on the receiving end though, how much data that is willing to accept.

Comment: I have no problem upload photos.. so this object with text can't be bigger than a photo.. .. why the down vote?

Comment: No necessarily an overall size limit, there are others, such as how many parameters will get accepted, maximum nesting levels, etc. If suhosin is in the mix, that might apply some even more fine-grained restrictions on particular aspects of such a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a ajax passing parameter issue so
Please assign your formData into one variable and pass it on ajax like below

```
var postData = {
            objEmp: formData 
   };

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/add_elementdata.php',
    method: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function (data) {
        //do you actions
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not change anything. Array 111 is still the last one.. of 199.

Comment: Need to check limitation of Apache & PHP below (and Increase size)

Apache : LimitRequestBody
& 
PHP : post_max_size

Comment: In apache i find no limit (No Limitrequestbody at all), and in php post_max_size is 200M.. so that cannot be the problem?!

Comment: increase post_max_size 300M and restart your server and again run your code I am sure you will get proper result

Comment: When i use your code now, the post returns empty..?! I set the post_max_size to 800M

Comment: I did remove the contentType.. and now i think it's working.. but.. the success function wont run... hmm

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0